# InstancedBufferGeometry.copy error in three.js

Tags: three.js, buffer-geometry

I am running a three.js example code, its three.js version is 0.124.

```
createObj() {
    const geometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();
    const baseGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 20, 2, 2, 6);
    
    // Copy attributes of the base Geometry to the instancing Geometry
    geometry.copy(baseGeometry);
}
```

when the code is running in 'geometry.copy(baseGeometry);', an error is popping up as showed as

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clone')
    at InstancedBufferGeometry.copy (three.module.js?cf64:10935)
    at InstancedBufferGeometry.copy (three.module.js?cf64:40628)
    at createObj (Clouds.js?d048:24)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InstancedBufferGeometry.copy()` only accepts another `InstancedBufferGeometry` object as the argument. You're trying to pass a legacy `Geometry` object ([THREE.Geometry was part of the core up until r125](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-geometry-will-be-removed-from-core-with-r125/22401), and you're using r124), so it breaks when performing that method when it notices that it's missing all the instancing properties.

[See here in the docs for using the `copy()` method](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=instanced#api/en/core/InstancedBufferGeometry.copy)

Comment: You can pass `BufferGeometry` into `.copy()` of `InstancedBufferGeometry`, just set `.instanceCount = Infinity` to the object of the `InstancedBufferGeometry`.

Comment: @prisoner849 That is correct with the latest versions, but in back in `r124` creating a `BoxGeometry` would be a legacy `Geometry` class, not a `BufferGeometry`.

Comment: Yeah, true. These days `BufferGeometry` had `.fromGeometry()` method. And also there was `BoxBufferGeometry`. If the author wants to use instancing, he has to work with attributes and all the other nice stuff, that belong `BufferGeometry` anyway.